# gcc -M how to print full path for dependencies

Tags: gcc

My gcc command is `gcc <other-stuff> -c -MD -o build/main.o main.c` and it outputs a `.p` file with the `make` dependency rules.

In that `.p` file, some files are listed with relative paths and some with absolute.

How do I force it to output absolute paths for all the files?

Comment: Can you add some minimal reproduction? I wonder how you got absolute paths here...

Comment: The absolute paths normally come from the global include paths. The only way that I know is to make sure that all -I specified include paths are absolute paths. That still might leave all includes that are specified relative to the source file.